# Laravel 5.3 Passport oauth - Single client multiple access token - Alexa

Tags: laravel, oauth-2.0, access-token, alexa-skills-kit, laravel-passport

I'm new to oAuth, but it's something I need to integrate for an Alexa home kit skill.

https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/alexa/alexa-skills-kit/docs/linking-an-alexa-user-with-a-user-in-your-system

I'm struggling with this, but I know that I need to use the authorization code grant.

After Googling around I thought I'd try to set this up using Laravel Passport (I plan to build a web-platform, so I'm not using Laravel purely for oAuth) - https://laracasts.com/series/whats-new-in-laravel-5-3/episodes/13

I've never used Laravel (new to PHP) but have spent a number of hours reading through Laracast guides, so I have a basic understanding.

I was able to setup a oAuth server using Laravel Passport, create a client, use the Client ID, Secret and Auth URLs, which I configured on the Alexa app and got the Alexa account linking working. Great.

The problem is, at the moment there is only one user, me. In the Alexa app you can only configure a single Client ID & Secret and the only way for me to link a user is via the access token that Alexa passes on in each action/request.

Looking at the oAuth tables, it seems the access token (no longer valid :) ) is linked to a user_id:

+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------+-----------+------+--------+---------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id                                                                               | user_id | client_id | name | scopes | revoked | created_at          | updated_at          | expires_at          |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------+-----------+------+--------+---------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| b96dbbbe1f52386bc098dcc106309504a1e546ec05d2a5cf8d37b7460e4ba84ec95e7ff2c0a2d037 |       1 |         9 | NULL | []     |       0 | 2017-01-16 08:28:18 | 2017-01-16 08:28:18 | 2018-01-16 08:28:18 |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------+-----------+------+--------+---------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+

In Laravel it's simple to register/create users, but at the moment each user can only create their own Client, which won't work here as Alexa is configured to use a single Client.

I need to find a way so that:

1 - Users can sign-in to my Laravel app using their credentials via the Alexa app (Alexa will pass on the state, client_id, response_type, scope, and redirect_uri as query string)

2 - If the user is authenticated my Laravel app will then generate an authorization code and pass that back to Alexa including the state

3 - Alexa uses that code to then request an access token and a refresh token

4 - When the access token is generated it's linked to the user_id of that user (customer), not the user_id who created the client (me)

5 - When the access token is refreshed, step 4 applies again.

I hope the above makes sense as I really struggled to put this into words. It's entirely possible that my understanding of oAuth is messed up too.

If I can accomplish the above steps, I'm sure I can easily create an API/method that allows me to work out which user an access token is assigned to using an SQL query.

I should also be able to workout how to display the oauth vue components so that only the admin user is able to see/use them to create clients.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using passport for first party apps, You can use [Password Grant Tokens](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/passport#password-grant-tokens).

Create a password client first

```
php artisan passport:client --password
```

Then pass the client id and client secret in form_params and the user credentials.

```
$http = new GuzzleHttp\Client;

$response = $http->post('http://your-app.com/oauth/token', [
    'form_params' => [
        'grant_type' => 'password',
        'client_id' => 4,
        'client_secret' => 'asefwwsgaqwsfwghhw3eqrfdhe',
        'username' => 'test@email.com',
        'password' => '123456',
        'scope' => '',
    ],
]);

return json_decode((string) $response->getBody(), true);
```

Then it will return a token and use it to pass to the `Authorization Bearer your-token` in the header.